# Installing cyrus-sasl installs saslauthd, but not the sysv init for CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, sasl

I've dug through all the cyrus-sasl distributions that seem like they would have the distrubution.  Searching the net turns up that there is a cyrus-sasl-authd package, but it doesn't show up in a yum list on my machine.

It seems like this should just be there, according to everything I've found on the web.  But it doesn't turn up.

Answer (score 3):

CentOS 7 is not using sysv init, but systemd, so there is no use for init scripts. Instead there are service files available under `/lib/systemd/system/saslauthd.service`.

You can start `saslauthd` by running `systemctl start saslauthd` and to make it start automatically, you need to run `systemctl enable saslauthd`, if it is your concern.